Sentence correction with adverb never and verb been
One of my friends commented on my photo "You deserve to live in pastel color palette! Such a doll,
I replied,
You have portrayed me in such a way where I have never been imagined myself.
Is this correct? I meant I have never imagined myself in the place (color palette) and the imaginary situation, it is kind of surreal meaning I wanted to put.
Please guide me if I am wrong or not


"You deserve to live in pastel color palette! Such a doll,

Palette is countable and as such requires a determiner or article.

You have portrayed me in such a way where I have never been imagined myself.

Where refers to a place. You need an adverb that expresses the manner in which you were portrayed.

You have portrayed me in such a way where I have never been imagined myself.

have never been imagined is a passive form of the verb and makes no sense. Reflexive verbs do not appear in the passive.

Agreed that "have never been imagined myself" is off. But "have never been fired myself" works, and so does "I myself have never been fired."

Thanks. I was desperately trying to think of an example and failed. However, your example is not reflexive.

Your reply:

You have portrayed me in such a way where I have never been imagined myself.

Is nearly grammatically correct but has a different meaning from what you appear to intend.

I would suggest omitting "such a way", which relates to the manner of description rather than a setting or place.

"… where I have never been imagined myself." means: "… in a place that others have not imagined me before."


I think a good way to say what you intended is:
"You have portrayed me where I have never imagined myself.
